# Azure DevOps Build Runs Stages in Blocks

Tags: azure-devops

Current Environment : Build Definition has multiple stages and jobs

Suggestion Required : Any possibilities to show build run stages in blocks like release runs. Build Runs normally appear in list view but can it be shown as blocks in release pipelines runs ?

[image: build]

to this

[image: release]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can it be shown as blocks in release pipelines runs ?

Of course it can.

In your first pic, it shown as list cause by your pipeline defined with multi-jobs instead of multi-stages.

As our designed, the stages will shown as blocks while there has multi stages configured in your YAML, and the jobs will display as list:

[image]

It YAML script structure should like this:

```
stages:
- stage: QA
  jobs:
  - job: BuildJob
    steps:
    - script: echo QA!
- stage: Pro
  jobs:
  - job: TestOnWindows
    steps:
    - script: echo Pro!
  - job: TestOnLinux
    steps:
    - script: echo Testing on Linux!
- stage: Enterprise
  jobs:
  - job: Deploy
    steps:
    - script: echo Enterprise!
```

**Note:**

If **there's only one stage** with multi-jobs configured in your pipeline, it will not show it as block, just list displayed.